# Cucumber Data Tables - using POJO/PROP file

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Is there a way to use a prop file value / POJO in the Data Table?

Example

```
Given <user> logs in to <url>
| user | url | 
| userOne | urlOne |
| userTwo | urlTwo |
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654972/pass-pojos-in-cucumber-example-table/59972488#59972488

Answer (score 2):

Add the keyword `Examples` above the table with examples, as follows:

```
Scenario outline: Log in with different users
  Given <user> logs in to <url>
  Examples:
  | user | url | 
  | userOne | urlOne |
  | userTwo | urlTwo |
```

Note that each line in the Examples table will be run by Cucumber as a separate Scenario / Example, based on the steps provided in the Scenario Outline.

Sidenote: In Cucumber, "DataTable" means something else; it's when you use a table with different fields & values (i.e. data) to create an object.

Comment: I mean - how do I map the "userOne" to a property file

Comment: You can do so in the implementation of your step definition, either directly or by calling a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654972/pass-pojos-in-cucumber-example-table/59972488#59972488). In above case You can achieve that using [cucumber extension](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) for [BDD2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) as below:

```
Given <user> logs in to <url>
...

Examples:
| user | url | 
| ${env1.user} | ${env1.url} |
| ${env2.user} | ${env2.url} |
```

You need to provide `env1.user`, `env1.url`, `env2.user`, `env2.url` properties in property file.